# What's the meaning of "simultaneous" in Tsung?

Tags: tsung

Here is my tsung.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/local/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="warning" version="1.0">

  <clients>
    <client host="localhost" use_controller_vm="true" maxusers="30000"/>
  </clients>

  <servers>
      <server host="127.0.0.1" port="9988" type="tcp"/>
  </servers>
<!--
  <monitoring>
    <monitor host="localhost" type="erlang"></monitor>
  </monitoring>
-->
  <load duration="90" unit="second">
    <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
      <users arrivalrate="300" unit="second" />
    </arrivalphase>
  </load>

  <options>
      <option name="thinktime" value="0" random="false" override="true"/>
      <option name="tcp_snd_buffer" value="4096"/>
      <option name="tcp_rcv_buffer" value="4096"/>
      <option name="ports_range" min="1025" max="65535"/>
  </options>

  <sessions>
    <session name="mysocket" probability="100" type="ts_raw">
      <request>
        <raw datasize="1" ack="local"></raw>
      </request>
    </session>
  </sessions>

</tsung>
```

It tests my socket program, but I cannot fully understand the Tsung report.

Please help to look at this pic, what does "simultaneous" mean?

[image: Simultaneous pic]

If anyone can help to tell me something about the report stats, that will be fine.

Stats like following(fetched from Tsung's manual):

```
users: Number of simultaneous users.
connected: Number of simultaneous connected users. new in 1.2.2.
```

Is it good or bad if `users` and `connected` is low?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http server will close the TCP socket if there is no action on it for a while or if it is overloaded. The opening and closing of TCP Sockets is handled automatically by Tsung. That said the 'connected' value is the current number 'users' that are connected to the server. Hope this helps